# What counts as a "fixed range" spell for Persistent Spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, metamagic

The **Persistent Spell** feat in Player's Guide to Faerûn allows a spell to last for 24 hours.  The spell to be persisted must have a personal range or fixed range.

I'm having trouble finding a definition of 'fixed range' for a spell.  One example given, [detect magic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/detectMagic.htm), has a range of 60 ft.  Are only spells with a non-variable range considered fixed?

Is a spell with range touch considered fixed?  While the 3.0 Faerûn campaign setting [errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/FRCSerrata.pdf) specifically excludes touch spells, 3.5 makes no mention of this.

Comment: The 3.5 errata specifically mentions that "Summon Monster" cannot be used with "persistent spell".  
http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20070731a

Comment: I've rescued the comments lost with the deleted answer [here in a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53839). Feel free to mine that to detail the question's conundrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No.

While the text of the feat is somewhat ambiguous, there are several indications in the rules that touch spells are not valid targets of Persistent Spell:

- If spells with "a fixed range" were intended to include touch spells, why are spells with Personal range called out as allowed?  After all, "Range:  Personal" is no more variable than "Range:  Touch."
- The errata for the book in which Persistent Spell was originally printed, Player's Guide to Faerun, explicitly said that touch spells could not be persisted.  While subsequent re-publishings of the spell did not include these changes, they're indicative of what the intent of the feat's wording was.
- Heroes of Battle p. 113 describes the effect of War Weaver's *Enlarge Tapestry* class feature:

> Spells
>   you cast through an eldritch tapestry have their range category increased: touch spells become close range, close-range spells become medium range, and medium-range spells become long range. Long-range spells and spells with fixed ranges are unaffected.

This rule explicitly draws a distinction between touch spells and spells with fixed ranges, and treats them differently, implying that touch spells are *not* included in the category of spells with fixed ranges.

Comment: I think the War Weaver description is as close to rules as written as I'll find.  I'm curious if you have opinions on using the Reach Spell feat (changing a touch range to 30ft) to qualify for Persistent Spell?

Comment: @Ryre, I think it probably works, and if your DM gives you trouble about the fact that it doesn't explicitly use the word "range" when describing its benefit, you can instead use Ocular Spell (LoM), which does.

Comment: If it helps any more, touch isn't necessarily a fixed range because the range of touch is given by the toucher's reach. For example shocking grasp has a range of 5 ft for a regular human wizard, but a range of 10 ft for an enlarged human wizard.