# What range categories exist for spells?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

The SRD gives us [a helpful list](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#range) of possible ranges for spells: Personal, Touch, Close, Medium, Long, Unlimited, and Range Expressed in Feet. However, this is clearly not a comprehensive list of all of the possible range categories in the game. For example, Persistent Spell's text claims that "Spells with a fixed or personal range can have their duration increased to 24 hours". This is despite, to my knowledge, "fixed range" not being a term that is defined in game or obviously understandable in plain English (e.g. [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95095/53359) shows one potential source of confusion).

This leads me to my question: What range categories does the game acknowledge, what are their definitions, and where are these definitions found or derived from?

Comment: This is a good question, and *should be* one we can handle... but I strongly suspect we cannot. Individual spells make up new range and area descriptions all the time, and going through all of them is a monumental task—and may result in an answer too large for Stack Exchange. I wish you luck, though.

Comment: @KRyan I'm not asking for a comprehensive list of ranges, I'm asking for categories of ranges. Hopefully that narrows things down. For example, I don't care if there's only one spell in the game with a range of exactly 1337 feet because that would presumably fall in to a category containing many other very long range spells with exact ranges.

Comment: I understood what you meant, and maintain my concern. Maybe the result wouldn’t be too much, but I for one could not even begin to imagine trying to collect it. That’s way more effort than I have ever put into a Stack Exchange answer, and I have put an enormous amount of effort into a fair number of answers around here.

Comment: I think an itemized and annotated 50-entry-or-more list strains the site's guidelines. An answer could, however, summarize some categories then provide a link to where specific information's available. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It sounds like a step in the right direction, particularly if it covers why the original question is so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here goes nothing. There are over 20 already in the PHB alone. Any ranges that have a particularly small number of spells that use it, I'll list the spells with.

- Personal
- Touch
- Short
- Medium
- Long
- Unlimited
- 0'
- 10'
- 10'/CL *Repulsion*
- 15' *Burning Hands* and *Color Spray*
- 20'
- 30'
- 40'
- 40'/CL *Control Winds*
- 50' *Bane/Bless*
- 60'
- 120' *Lightning Bolt*
- 1/2 Mile *Diminish Plants* and *Plant Growth*
- 1 Mile *Prying Eyes/Greater*
- 1 Mile/CL *Whispering Wind*
- 2 Miles *Control Weather*
- 5 Miles *Helping Hand*
- Special
- Varies (this category exclusively contains spells that can replicate multiple other spells i.e. *Wish*, *Miracle*, *Shades*, etc.)

Comment: [Range](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#range) says, "A spell’s range is the maximum distance from you that the spell’s effect can occur, **as well as** the maximum distance at which you can designate the spell’s point of origin" (emphasis mine). However, for some spells that have range entries this is nonsense—for example, a *burning hands* or *lightning bolt* spell typically can't have as its point of origin a grid intersection that isn't adjacent to the caster's space! In other words, by the *PH* definition, some spells' listed ranges are not *actually* their ranges.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yes, technically, all of the *Cone* shape spells are wrong. The issue arises that the "range" is these instances are actually describing the range of the spells *effect* not the range of the spell *itself*. All of the *Cone* spells should have a range of *Personal* instead, with the effect as an "X foot long cone", but I went with the official ranges rather than the "real" ranges. *Line* spells like *Lightning Bolt* have the same issue.